# Cuddle braces in flex

Tags: apache-flex, curly-braces

How can I force flex to cuddle my curly-braces instead of putting them on a new line?

Comment: What language/IDE/text editor/development environment are you using? The answer will be different depending on what language/environment you're using.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this anyway?  It makes your code less readable (which generally isn't a huge problem for generated code, but still).

Comment: I'm using the Flex IDE for as3.  The fact that it makes your code less readable is completely an opinion - http://www.gskinner.com/blog/archives/2008/11/curly_braces_to.html.

Comment: Cuddly braces, snuggly brackets. Awww :)

Comment: Just don't. You're not trying to save paper, are you?

Comment: @Imagist: not everyone agrees on the braces-on-the-next-line thing. Personally I've never understood it. It makes your code artificially "tall".

Comment: Why ask why? David has his reasons, unless you personally will be following up on his code you have no reason to argue with why he chooses to format his code that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to make the assumption that you are talking about Flex Builder.  I'm specifically using Flex Builder 4 beta (Flash Builder), but I think this applies for Flex Builder 3.

When asking fb to create a new actionscript class, you can adjust the template and set it to cuddle the braces, but only for the class definition.  The template settings can be found under Window -> Preferences -> Flash Builder -> File Templates.

A better option is the Flex Formatter plug-in, which can be found at Source-Forge [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/flexformatter/files/).  Note the installation instructions [here](http://sourceforge.net/project/shownotes.php?release_id=698747) which are different depending on which version of Eclipse you are running.

Once you get the plugin installed, you'll see a number of new setting available under Window -> Preferences -> Flex Formatting.  The one you are looking for is buried a bit.  Look under Flex Formatting -> ActionScript -> Newlines/Wrapping -> Line Breaks -> Brace Style.

Set as desired.

Once that is all done, just go to your selected actionscript file, and press the Ctrl+Shift+F keyboard shortcut.  And there you have it.

Easy Peasy, Lemon Squeezy.

Comment: Does this plugin work on-the-fly or only when file is saved/format command called?